# How do I create an oracle view where the last name begins with 'S''?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to create a view that allows my to select all the users with a last name beginning with 'S' based of the following:

```
CREATE TABLE cteam_Users(
    UserLastName  VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    );


INSERT INTO cteam_Users
    (  UserLastName,)
    VALUES ('Sam');

INSERT INTO cteam_Users
    (  UserLastName,)
    VALUES ('Tam');

Create view cteam_V1 As 
SELECT UserLastName From cteam_Users 
Where UserLastName = 's%'; 

SELECT  * FROM cteam_V1;
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `like` operator as following:

```
Create view cteam_V1 As 
SELECT UserLastName From cteam_Users 
Where lower(UserLastName) like 's%';
```

I have used `lower` function for case insensitive matches.

Comment: that will prevent index usage in case UserLastName is indexed (unless it's an FBI), and that may prevent offload to storage cells in case you're on exadata (I'm not sure about `lower` in particular, but some native sql functions don't get offloaded as well as all pl/sql)